# Is there a way to use ASP.NET Bundles cross applications

Tags: asp.net, bundle

I use the ASP.NET Web Optimization package to bundle and minify javascript/css files.

I have a few ASP.NET applications using same javascript/css files, and now I setup bundles in each application.

I wonder if there is a way to register bundles in one of these applications, and other applications just use it.

The key problem is how to get the hash code of the query string in other application than the app in which bundles are registered.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible. Well, there's nothing stopping you from rendering styles and scripts bundles from an external app. You can manually pull the bundled resources using a native `script` tag and specifying the absolute url...

```
<script src="http://domain.com/bundles/jquery"></script>
```

or using the `Scripts.Render` helper in razor...

```
@Scripts.Render("http://domain.com/bundles/jquery")
```

however, you will have problems with caching if the resources server changes the contents of these styles/script bundles because the consuming application will not be able to resolve the caching query string. The reason why it can't resolve it seems to be obvious...the `Scripts.Render` helper uses the current application's Web Optimization framework to render the caching query string, yet, the consuming applications use a different instance of the web optimization framework.

I have no idea how this works behind the scenes, the only thing I know for sure is that the caching querystring changes when the bundles content (files) change. I'm guessing that the caching query string uses some sort of hashing algorithm based on the machine key value or something...that's just me speculating but you can certainly have a look at the source code if you're keen in getting to the bottom of this...

http://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

#### Suggestion 1

Because there doesn't seem to be any workaround for these issue, if it is crucial to your project to have an external resource server to serve common styles and scripts to other applications. I'd just access them manually as stated above and version the resources by appending a number at the end of the bundles name...

```
@Scripts.Render("http://server.com/bundles/name1")
```

And update your application's to reference the correct version every time you update the resources to avoid browsers from rendering a old cached version.

#### Suggestion Two

Another approach (which doesn't bring anything new to the one above) would be to implement your own optimization routine which doesn't seem to be that hard. It might give some flexibility is you require it. Have a look at this [Ayende's article](http://ayende.com/blog/13314/elegant-code-raccoon-blogs-css-controller)...make sure you read the comments as well

Personally, I don't like the way he appends file names to the querystring, but, you don't really have to, as long as you are able to resolve the bundles' url.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this in the following way, but at the cost that in the other applications these are rendered already optimized, and not one by one as is the case when using bundling with debug builds.

Lets say you create a new CDNController class in the application that has defined all your bundles:

```
public class CDNController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Script(string id)
    {
        string url = BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl(string.Format("~/bundles/{0}", id));
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return Redirect(url);
    }
}
```

You need to call the action method with the bundle id. If you would normally write:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery)
```

You will need to replace this with a call to your new action method. If the hosting/main application is installed under the application path of `/mainapp' you would write:

```
<script src="/mainapp/CDN/Script/jquery"></script>
```

Unlike the first way this does not require you to register the bundles in the other applications, it just requires that you write an absolute path. The new action method requests the bundle url (including the cryptic hash) and does a redirect to that address. For example it could redirect to: `/mainapp/bundles/frameworks?v=pznFYVbTrRKNlRAgSb6KWMMjBI0qJjNleRyztT6W1gU1`. This address will always render the bundle minified and bundled together.

You could create a similar action method for rendering CSS bundles as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var domain="http://www.google.com";

Styles.DefaultTagFormat = "<link href=\"" + domain + "{0}\" rel=\"stylesheet\"/>";
Scripts.DefaultTagFormat = "<script src=\"" + domain + "{0}\"  type=\"text/javascript\"></script>";
```

When you call:

```
Styles.Render("~/masterpagecss")

Scripts.Render("~/masterpagejstop")
```

This will render like this:

```
<link href="http://www.google.comm/masterpagecss?v=cUYMJ2uO6cjidXEjFnWzUVvVS4_GR9OGA45p3oKZJSQ1" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="http://www.google.com/masterpagejstop?v=Oay1Ofn63qSMuPEhfoMe9tPsA_Hp9HeG2rAEcaA6RWk1"></script>
```

I tried it in my web site and it worked perfectly.

Just make sure that the domain that you used is a binding of your web site, in that we can have access to the files.

Comment: When defining the bundles in your MVC website, do you use the full URL for the CDN site?  If so, could you please provide an example?  I'm using the following and it's not working: `bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css", "http://cdn-site.com/Content/css")`.  More details about my issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48179363/accessing-cdn-bundles-on-different-asp-net-mvc-site)